# TypeError: get_appsettings() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am new to pyramid and have checked out a code that I am trying to run locally the error that it shows so far is

```
c:\env\felt>..\Scripts\initialize_felt_db.exe staging.ini
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\env\Scripts\initialize_felt_db-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('felt==0.0', 'console_scripts', 'initialize_felt_db')()
  File "c:\env\felt\felt\scripts\initializedb.py", line 51, in main
    settings = get_appsettings(config_uri, options=options)
TypeError: get_appsettings() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

line 51 is :

```
settings = get_appsettings(config_uri, options=options)
```

the sqlalchemy url in staging.ini is :

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql://root:@127.0.0.1/felt
```

Why am I getting the error? I am on windows 7 by the way. I followed this *[install](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html)* link for setting up my virtual env.

Please do let me know if I still need to post more codes for this question. Cheers and thanks a lot

Comment: [options is not an argument](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/api/paster.html#pyramid.paster.get_appsettings) - It should be name instead i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd change that line to :

```
 settings = get_appsettings(config_uri)
```

That's the way it's created by scaffold on the linux box.